# Error while installing app using Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

Whenever I hit the instant run button to install application, Android Studio gives me following error

> Session 'app': Error Installing restart patches

in the event window.

Answer (score 0):

Once uninstall app then install. Try it !!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes

Comment: Please read [answer] and remove the signature from your post. (Those are two separate things). There's already a link to your profile under every post you make, and you can put anything you want on your profile.

Comment: I've reformatted your answer, but in the future, keep in mind that this site uses [Markdown](https://www.markdowntutorial.com/), and you can get some really nice-looking posts if you learn to use it. It's a very common tool and definitely worth learning as a developer.